# Windows file managers that can display file sizes with binary prefixes

Tags: windows, file-management

Please recommend Windows file managers that can display file sizes with binary prefixes, and that [display files smaller than 1KiB as bytes](https://superuser.com/q/1569825/386552).

For example, the binary prefix would change the display from KB (kilobytes) to KiB (kibibytes), MB (megabytes) to MiB (mebibytes), GB (gigabytes) to GiB (gibibytes).
I find it confusing how SI units are used, when in fact Windows does not use SI units for the values of the sizes of files. The sizes of files are given in base 2, not base 10.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1541-2002

My attempt to find appropriate software included installing FreeCommander XE (recommended in [this article](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-file-manager.htm)). But, I [don't think it has the feature](https://freecommander.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=10784).

Comment: Haven't checked lately, but SpeedCommander should fit the bill.

Comment: Are you concerned about prefixes or the numbers themselves? The sizes are always given in base 2, as you say, and I don't know any software that does otherwise (it makes little sense, for various reasons). But this really makes the issue moot: whatever it says, it's base-2, and everyone knows it. Is it just to be pedantic with designations? (Nothing wrong with that IMO). How about those that _just_ use a prefix letter (35 - 1.2 k - 2.3 M etc)? Technically, this is not a prefix anymore but just a designator, and doesn't have to conform to IEEE.

Comment: I'm more concerned about the prefixes than the numbers themselves.